# How to put jquery with cordova?

Tags: jquery, cordova

I made this code to use jquery mobile in cordova, but whenever I use an Android command from cordova, it doesn't work.

I've tried putting the DeviceReady function inside document ready, but it doesn't work, is it really possible to use both together?

```
$("#form_login").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var username = $("#textinput-hide_login").val();
        var password = $("#textinput-hide_password").val();

        if (username === "1308" && password === "1308") {
            //alert("Login bem-sucedido!");
            navigator.notification.alert('Você está pronto para usar o aplicativo!', alertDismissed, 'Dispositivo Pronto', 'OK');
        } else {
            //alert("Credenciais inválidas. Tente novamente.");
            navigator.notification.alert('Você está pronto para usar o aplicativo!', alertDismissed, 'Dispositivo Pronto', 'OK');
        }
    });    

    $("#hide_password").click(function(){
        navigator.notification.alert('Você está pronto para usar o aplicativo!', alertDismissed, 'Dispositivo Pronto', 'OK');
    })
```

Comment: There is no issue using jQuery with Cordova. Maybe show us how you embedded jQuery into your project

Comment: I created this basic script to test if the function works but on the cell phone it doesn't execute the alerts

Comment: document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
        function onDeviceReady() {
        
            $(document).on('volumeupbutton', callbackFunctionUp);

           
        function callbackFunctionUp() {
            alert('Botão de volume para cima pressionado');
        }

Comment: No, I mean, you need to add jQuery as a script to your page

Comment: is this script?

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/soft.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css">
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>